# List comprehension: making lists of lists

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

hi im trying to make a function in haskell that takes a number a makes a partion of it using lists i.e. for number `4` it would create `[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[4]]`. I was thinking of using list comprehension for this where it would create list x and then create further lists using numbers from [1...n] (n being the partition number I would want) where the sum of the list created would be equal to n.

The code I have created so far is-

```
partions (n:xs) = [[x|x<-[1...n], sum[x]==n]]|xs<-[1..]]
```

but obiviously it doesnt work, any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: Rolled back the edit which killed the post

Comment: And again. @dave, why are you attempting to delete both your questions? :/

Answer (score 4):

I suggest trying recursion: To obtain the partitions of n, iterate over the numbers i = 1 to n, and recursively generate the partitions of (n-i), the base case being that the only partition of 1 is 1 itself, and the partition of 0 is the empty list.

Comment: Making `partition 0` be `[[]]` instead of `[]` may help make the recursion simpler.

Comment: @Joey That's true. I was a bit sloppy in my description of what I'd do.

Answer (score 3):

How about this...

```
import Data.List (nub, sort)

parts :: Int -> [[Int]]
parts 0 = []
parts n = nub $ map sort $ [n] : [x:xs | x <- [1..n`div`2], xs <- parts(n - x)]
```

Trying it:

```
*Main Control.Monad> forM [1..5] (print . parts)
[[1]]
[[2],[1,1]]
[[3],[1,2],[1,1,1]]
[[4],[1,3],[1,1,2],[1,1,1,1],[2,2]]
[[5],[1,4],[1,1,3],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,2],[2,3]]
```

I think it's correct, if not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little rusty with Haskell, but maybe the following code can guide you to find the solution.

```
parts :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
parts 0 p = [[]]
parts x p = [(y:ys) | y <-[p..x], ys <- (parts (x - y) y)]
```

And then you would have to call parts with x = n, and p = 1.

**EDIT**

I've fixed the base case when x equals 0 to return a list with a single item, being that item an empty list. Now it works fine :)

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but I get an error: Couldn't match expected type t1->t against inferred type [[Int]]. In the expression: parts 4 1. In the definition of 'it': it = parts 4 1

Comment: @Matt I'm no expert, but I think you may be using `it` in another context, and the type inference for `it` doesn't match with `[[Int]]`. I've called `parts 4 1` using WinHugs and the output was exactly as @dave's example

Comment: You shouldn't define 'it'.  'it' is always the result of the last calculation in GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

I found it helpful to define an auxiliary function, `partitionsCap`, which does not let any of the items be larger than a given value.  Used recursively, it can be used to only produce the [monotonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) decreasing results you want (i.e. no `[1,3,1]` when you already have `[1,1,3]`):

```
partitions :: Int -> [[Int]]
partitions n = partitionsCap n n

partitionsCap :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
partitionsCap cap n
    | n < 0  = error "partitions: negative number"
    | n == 0 = [[]]
    | n > 0  = [i : p | i <- [hi,hi-1..1], p <- partitionsCap i (n-i)]
               where hi = min cap n
```

---

At the heart of the algorithm is the idea that, when partitioning N, you take `i` from `n` down to 1, and prepend `i` to the partitions of `n-i`.  Simplified:

```
concat [map (i:) $ partitions (n-i) | i <- [n,n-1..1]]
```

but wrong:

```
> partitions 3
[[3],[2,1],[1,2],[1,1,1]]
```

We want that `[1,2]` to go away.  Hence, we need to cap the partitions we're prepending to so they won't go above `i`:

```
concat [map (i:) $ partitionsCap i (n-i) | i <- [hi,hi-1..1]]
where hi = min cap n
```

Now, to clean it up: that *concat* and *map* so close together got my attention.  A little background: list comprehensions and the list monad are [very closely related](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension#List_monad), and *concatMap* is the same as `>>=` with its arguments flipped, in the list monad.  So I wondered: can those *concat* and *map* somehow turn into a `>>=`, and can that `>>=` somehow sweet-talk its way into the list comprehension?

In this case, the answer is yes :-)

```
[i : p | i <- [hi,hi-1..1], p <- partitionsCap i (n-i)]
where hi = min cap n
```