# fast method to list all possible combination of numbers which sum to a const number

Tags: algorithm

Assume we need to list four numbers A, B, C, and D.
The sum of A+B+C+D is 10 and the value of each number is in the range of [0, 10].

Find all the possible combination.

The brute-force way is as follows:

```
for (int A = 0; A <=10; ++A)
  for (int B = 0; B <=10-A; ++B)
  {
   if (A + B > 10) break;    
   for (int C = 0; C <=10-A-B; ++C)
   {
    if (A + B + C > 10) break;
    for (int D = 0; D <=10-A-B-C; ++D)
    {
       if (A + B + C + D == 10)
       {
         cout << "A: " << A << ",B: " << B << ",C: " << C << ",D: " << D << endl;
         break;
       }
       else if (A + B + C + D > 10)
         break;
    }
   }
  }
```

Q> Is there a better solution?

FYI: code is updated based on suggestion from @rici

Comment: Does 7,1,1,1 count or do the numbers need to be unique?  Is 1,2,3,4 considered same as 2,1,3,4 or no?  Perhaps it doesn't matter?

Comment: The phrase to search for is "integer partition" (or "composition" if you care about order.)  Most definitions exclude zeros but that's easy enough to work around.

Comment: for a start, it should be obvious that you can replace `for (int D = 0; D <=10; ++D) { if (A + B + C + D == 10)` with `D = 10 - (A + B + C)` at a considerable saving of time.

Comment: order does matter since the sequence is for [A, B, C, D].

Comment: @q: you don't need those `if` statements since they mirror the condition in the preceding `for` statement. And you still needlessly iterate `D` from `0` until it reaches the only possible value. But you're almost there.

Comment: I think this answer in Haskell, based on another SO answer, might be one possible solution (this case would be `partitions 10 4`) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388241/algorithm-to-partition-distribute-sum-between-buckets-in-all-unique-ways/15390241#15390241

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a method to enumerate the [partitions of an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).  The linked wikipedia page lays out a few ways of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
void print4Partitions(int num) {
    for (int A=1; A<num-3; A++) {
        for (int B=A+1; B<num-A-2; B++) {
            for (int C=B+1; C<num-(A+B)-1; C++) {
                int D = num-A-B-C;
                printf("%d %d %d %d\n", A, B, C, D);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main ideas here are:

- You really don't need to loop over the last number: it can be simply computed, as @nci mentions, as `A`, `B`, `C`, and the number to be partitions uniquely determine `D`.
- You can limit your loops instead of testing and using `break` statements, which should result in faster code.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code would only ever give {1 2 3 4}, since it doesn't allow repeated numbers, eg {2 2 2 4}. You're also assuming that order doesn't matter, eg {1 3 2 4}, where the OP said it did(in a comment). The bulleted points are good, though.